# Upgrading to new Ubuntu

Tags: upgrade, backup

I'm trying to download the new version following the steps given in https://ubuntu.com/download. i've got as far as step 3, but nothing it says will happen after that is happening. it also said to back up my existing Ubuntu installation before i update, but i've no idea how to do this. i'm really not very technical at all, so any easy to follow help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Open a Terminal. Enter the command `sudo apt update`. Hit Enter. When prompted, enter your password. It WON'T show on the screen, but your keystrokes are indeed being registered. So enter your password carefully. Hit Enter. Use your cursor to Copy the entire output. Paste that entire output into your Question above.

Comment: @user535733 Would you mind making that an answer, please?

Comment: It's not an answer. It's merely the first step to diagnosing the actual problem, since the description is (understandably) vague. There may be many more steps.

Comment: To OP: Please [edit] your question to include both your current Ubuntu version and what you're trying to update to. Also, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7809/how-to-back-up-my-entire-system) for taking a backup

Comment: are you going to do a clean install(you say you are downloading ubuntu)from a usb or are you trying to upgrade your current version to a newer version,please edit this information into your question,please tell what version you have and what version you are upgrading to this is important information for the one(s) answering.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What directories should I backup before a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1241584/what-directories-should-i-backup-before-a-clean-install-of-ubuntu-20-04)